# How to prevent space in regex in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, console.log

I have this JavaScript code below to remove spaces in the given words (ستاک ئەڤەفلۆو), and I tried it in Console.log, but it has a problem.

```js
var text = "ئایا ستاک ئەڤەفلۆو مانای چییە؟ دووبارە ستاک ئەڤەفلۆو مانای چییە؟";

text = text.replace(
            new RegExp("(^|\\s|_|«|»|\\[|\\(|\\<|\\>|\\')(ستاک ئەڤەفلۆو)(?= |«|»|\\.|،|_|\\]|\\s|\\:|\\)|\\<|\\>|؟|\\'|\\!|$)", 'g'),
            function (x) { return x.replace(/ /gi, ''); } // 'i' is just to trick bidi algorithm on code view
        );
```

The following is the wrong output:

```js
ئایاستاکئەڤەفلۆو مانای چییە؟ دووبارەستاکئەڤەفلۆو مانای چییە؟
```

Which removes the space before the given string, so it merges the given string with the previous word.

The output should be:

```js
ئایا ستاکئەڤەفلۆو مانای چییە؟ دووبارە ستاکئەڤەفلۆو مانای چییە؟
```

Thanks!

Comment: x.replace(" ") or x.replace(/[ ]/gi);

Comment: @ControlAltDel I tried these, but didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest removing escapes by merging single char alternatives into character classes, and fix the issue by removing whitespaces in Group 2 only, not in Group 1.

```js
var text = "ئایا ستاک ئەڤەفلۆو مانای چییە؟ دووبارە ستاک ئەڤەفلۆو مانای چییە؟";

text = text.replace(
  new RegExp("(^|[\\s_«»[(<>'])(ستاک ئەڤەفلۆو)(?=[«».،_\\]\\s:)<>؟'!]|$)", 'g'),
  function (x, punct, word) { return (punct || "") + word.replace(/\s+/gi, ''); }
);
console.log(text)
```

So, the regex means

- `(^|[\s_«»[(<>'])` - Capturing group 1 (`punct` in the replacement callback function): start of string, or a whitespace, `_`, `«`, `»`, `[`, `(`, `<`, `>` or `'`
- `(ستاک ئەڤەفلۆو)` - Capturing group 2 (`word`): some phrase
- `(?=[«».،_\]\s:)<>؟'!]|$)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location in string that is immediately followed by `«`, `»`, `.`, `،`, `_`, `]`, whitespace, `:`, `)`, `<`, `>`, `؟`, `'`, `!` or end of string.

Upon a match, `punct` (if matched) is appended to the `word` that is stripped from all whitespaces (with `word.replace(/\s+/gi, '')`).